# How do Biblical Unitarians explain the use of the singular in 2 Thessalonians 2:16-17?

Tags: trinity, biblical-unitarian, 2-thessalonians

2 Thessalonians 2:16-17 is

> "16 Now may our Lord Jesus Christ Himself and God our Father, who by
> grace has loved us and given us eternal comfort and good hope,
> 17 encourage your hearts and strengthen you in every good word and deed." (Berean Standard Bible)

This seems a bit strange, as St. Paul is mentioning Jesus **and** the Father, but then uses singular verbs at 17. One explanation of this sometimes given by Trinitarians is that St. Paul is gesturing toward the Trinitarian nature of God with this grammatical usage.

How do Biblical Unitarians understand Paul's grammar at 2 Thessalonians 2:16-17?

Comment: και ο θεος και πατηρ ημων ο αγαπησας ημας _and the God and Father of us who loved us_. The original Greek is clear in that one Person (the God and Father of us who loved us) is being referred to. The article 'the' brackets both 'God' and 'Father' (Sharp's rule). I don't see how there can be any ambiguity here. Perhaps ask this question in SE-BH for a full explanation of the Greek construct.

Comment: Also  note the singular Aorist verbs in v. 17

Comment: @NigelJ Ambiguity about what?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Right. What do you think follows from that?

Comment: @NigelJ I've modified the question to focus on 17.

Comment: Same conclusion as Elohim in Genesis 1:1.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 ... and that is?